# How to read an excel file using Java and add the contents to a mySQL database | Java | Apache Tomcat | Eclipse Editor

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have wriiten a code to read an xlxs file using Apache poi. However, I keep getting the error :

```
No valid entries or contents found, this is not a valid OOXML (Office Open XML) file
```

The servlet is supposed to read the contents of excel file and store the data accordingly to a mySQL database.
The code is given below:

This class uploads the file to server:

```
package finalApplication;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;








public class uploader extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        try {
            ServletFileUpload sf=new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());

            List<FileItem> multifiles = sf.parseRequest(request);
            //String file="";
            
            for(FileItem item : multifiles)
            {
                
                String filename =item.getName();
                
                item.write(new File("C:\\Users\\khuha\\eclipse-workspace\\finalApplication"+"\\"+filename));
                HttpSession session=request.getSession();
                

                session.setAttribute("file",filename);
                System.out.println(session.getAttribute("file"));


            }
            

            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() +"/sheetsdetails.jsp");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {  
            
            
            System.out.println(ex);



        }

    }

}
```

This file processes the uploaded file

```
package finalApplication;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookType;

public class dataCollect extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        //connection to mysql
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Aithent";
        String uname="root";
        String pass="mysql";

        String dbUquery="use Aithent;";


        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");


            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,uname,pass);
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            st.execute(dbUquery);
            // database configured------------------
            //getting session -------------
            HttpSession session=request.getSession();
            String filename=(String) session.getAttribute("file");



            //Excel file processing-----------------------------
            try(FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\khuha\\eclipse-workspace\\firstDemo\\"+filename);){
                XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
                int sheetnum=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sheetnumber"));
                XSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(sheetnum-1);




                Row firstRow=sheet.getRow(0);
                Iterator<Row> itr=sheet.iterator();
                // Keys stores column names--------------------------------
                int colnum=firstRow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
                String keys[]=new String[colnum-1];

                Iterator<Cell> FirstrowIterator=sheet.getRow(0).cellIterator();{
                    int a=1;
                    while(FirstrowIterator.hasNext()){
                        Cell date_cell=firstRow.getCell(1);
                        String sdate=date_cell.getStringCellValue();
                        boolean isSingleDigit=Pattern.matches("[0-9]-[A-Z]*[a-z]+",sdate);
                        boolean isDoubleDigit=Pattern.matches("[0-9][0-9]-[A-Z]*[a-z]+",sdate);
                        String new_date;
                        String new_month;
                        if (isSingleDigit==true){
                            new_date="0"+sdate.substring(0);
                            new_month=sdate.substring(2-5);
                            keys[a]=appUtils.date_maker(new_date,new_month);




                        }
                        else if (isDoubleDigit=true){
                            new_date=sdate.substring(0,2);
                            new_month=sdate.substring(3,6);
                            keys[a]=appUtils.date_maker(new_date,new_month);




                        }


                    }


                }
                String tbquery="create table if not exists "+filename+"( Name varchar(100));";
                st.execute(tbquery);
                int i=0;
                while (i<colnum){

                    String addQuery="Alter table "+filename+" add "+ keys[i]+" varchar(15);";
                    st.execute(addQuery);
                    i++;
                }



                while(itr.hasNext()) {


                    //Values stores tuple info------------------------------
                    String values[]=new String[colnum-1];
                    Row row=itr.next();
                    Cell name_cell=row.getCell(0);
                    String name=name_cell.getStringCellValue();
                    values[0]=name;
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator=row.cellIterator();
                    int k=1;
                    while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Cell cell=cellIterator.next();
                        String dbEntry;

                        if (cell.getRowIndex()!=0 && cell.getStringCellValue().equals("")&& cell.getColumnIndex()!=0){
                            dbEntry="Blank";
                        }
                        else if(cell.getRowIndex()!=0 && ( cell.getStringCellValue().equals("F")| cell.getStringCellValue().equals("f"))&& cell.getColumnIndex()!=0) {
                            dbEntry="Full Day";
                        }
                        else if(cell.getRowIndex()!=0 && ( cell.getStringCellValue().equals("H")| cell.getStringCellValue().equals("h"))&& cell.getColumnIndex()!=0) {
                            dbEntry="Half Day"; 
                        }
                        else if(cell.getRowIndex()!=0 &&( cell.getStringCellValue().equals("L")| cell.getStringCellValue().equals("l"))&& cell.getColumnIndex()!=0) {
                            dbEntry="Leave";
                        }
                        else {
                            dbEntry="Invalid Entry";
                        }
                        values[k]=dbEntry;
                        k++;
                    }
                    String insertQ="INSERT into "+filename+"Values (";
                    int l=0;
                    while (l<colnum) {
                        if (l!=colnum-2){
                            insertQ.concat(values[l]+",");


                        }
                        else {
                            insertQ.concat(values[l]+");");
                        }

                    }
                    st.execute(insertQ);



                }



                wb.close();
            }



            catch(Exception e){ 

                e.printStackTrace();  
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e1) {
            System.out.println(e1);


        }
    }
}
```

The excel file looks like this
[image: The header column is the dates in a text format and the first row stores the names]

The servlet is getting input from another servlet in form of session attribute file. and the sheetnum is obatined from a jsp.

This image shows the output:
[!output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDLz5.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDLz5.png)
If you look at the file explorer you can see the null file.

Comment: Just checked to see what value is the attribute file returning. It return Null. I believe that is the problem here.

Comment: Open the troublesome file in Excel, do a save-as, and see what format Excel thinks it really is in? (Excel will happily open files with the wrong extension without warning!)

Comment: Actually the problem is that everytime I upload a file a dummy null file is also created I checked in the directory. I will update the question to include the code for the servlet used for uploading

Comment: I'm hesitant to help debug your current attempt. I'd suggest trying a different approach that doesn't involve 2 servers or putting the file on disc and see if you can get the solution you're after.